# ARFF file extension to csv binary executable

Tags: bash, csv, weka, file-conversion, arff

Thanks in advance for the help.

I'm looking for a binary executable to convert an .arff into a .csv in a bash script.  Ideally something that I could run along the lines of

```
#! /bin/sh
... some stuff....
converstionFunc input.arff output.csv
... some more stuff ...
```

Looking into writing this myself I found that weka provides a library that I could utilize that would allow me to do this.  However, as much as I looked for it, I could not find it.  I have weka installed on my mac and after looking around for the library I still was unable to find it.

Does anyone know where I may find such an executable, or able to point me where I could get a hold of the weka java library that would let me write it myself?

Comment: Would a python script be acceptable? Assuming that your arff is not too complicated, this should be a very simple conversion.

Comment: anything would be acceptable.  I have several thousand arff files that I would like to convert to csv.  Ideally I would like the conversion to be as fast as possible, but I'm willing to settle for anything that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clone this github repository. It contains an arff2csv tool in the "tools" subdirectory.

arff2csv is designed to run in pipes of unix commandline tools.

https://github.com/jeroenjanssens/data-science-at-the-command-line

arff2csv is a one-line shell-script that calls another shell script that calls weka.jar,

so it needs java installed on your machine; and note that arff2csv needs Weka version 3.6. (According to my experiments the newer v3.7 does not work.)

The script wants this environment variable set:

```
export WEKAPATH=/path/to/wekajar-dirname
```

and then you can do

```
cat /opt/smallapps/weka-stable/data/breast-cancer.arff | arff2csv > breast-cancer.arff.csv
```

Large arffs need some time to get processed.

You can read J.Janssen's book (see repo-README) for a bit more info.

Comment: I ended up finding a workaround that allowed me to avoid the creation of arff files.  The solution you have given appears that it would work though.

Answer (score 0):

Try an web search for `arff2csv`. It looks like there are lots of utilities out there.